# XYZ tiles shifting coordinates

Tags: tiles, mapnik

I'm using tilestrata and mapnik server to host geotiff map.
I'm getting very strange behaviour:

[image: Doubling map]

Basically, rendered tile shifts across map in strange fashion.
The transformation from lat/long to XYZ is known and I implemented it correctly (works on other map).

*One lead I can think of is the fact, that the map uses different units for pixel width and height (other maps I was using had square pixels).*

**EDIT:** Converted map to have "square" pixels using gdalwarp and gdaltranslate -  bug is still on!

Any ideas what can cause such a strange behaviour?

Can I somehow set different aspect ratio of pixel in proj4 srs info?

Here is the gdalinfo from the file:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: GIG_halda_jadwiga_orto_2cm.tif
Size is 40549, 35453
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (19.165103727574930,50.334287477469992)
Pixel Size = (0.000000280890000,-0.000000179799000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  19.1651037,  50.3342875) ( 19d 9'54.37"E, 50d20' 3.43"N)
Lower Left  (  19.1651037,  50.3279131) ( 19d 9'54.37"E, 50d19'40.49"N)
Upper Right (  19.1764935,  50.3342875) ( 19d10'35.38"E, 50d20' 3.43"N)
Lower Right (  19.1764935,  50.3279131) ( 19d10'35.38"E, 50d19'40.49"N)
Center      (  19.1707986,  50.3311003) ( 19d10'14.88"E, 50d19'51.96"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 20275x17727, 10138x8864, 5069x4432, 2535x2216, 1268x1108, 634x554, 317x277, 159x139
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
  Overviews of mask band: 20275x17727, 10138x8864, 5069x4432, 2535x2216, 1268x1108, 634x554, 317x277, 159x139
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 20275x17727, 10138x8864, 5069x4432, 2535x2216, 1268x1108, 634x554, 317x277, 159x139
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
  Overviews of mask band: 20275x17727, 10138x8864, 5069x4432, 2535x2216, 1268x1108, 634x554, 317x277, 159x139
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 20275x17727, 10138x8864, 5069x4432, 2535x2216, 1268x1108, 634x554, 317x277, 159x139
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
  Overviews of mask band: 20275x17727, 10138x8864, 5069x4432, 2535x2216, 1268x1108, 634x554, 317x277, 159x139
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
  Overviews: 20275x17727, 10138x8864, 5069x4432, 2535x2216, 1268x1108, 634x554, 317x277, 159x139
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I have reached the root of the problem:
It seems that **mapnik** does some sort of operation on map extent after setting it:

Consider "bbox" coordinates in latlong units for troublesome tiles:

```
data = [minx, miny, maxx, maxy]
```

I'm setting my map extent using it:

```
map.extent = data
```

As a result of: `console.log(map.extent)` I get array that is different than `data`.

Why and what mapnik is doing in `map.extent`setter is yet to be decided.

EDIT:
Solved by adding option:

`map.aspect_fix_mode = mapnik.Map.ASPECT_RESPECT;`